# Using rvest to scrape a website w/ a login page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Here's my code:

```
library(rvest)

#login
url <- "https://secure.usnews.com/member/login?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fpremium.usnews.com%2Fbest-graduate-schools%2Ftop-medical-schools%2Fresearch-rankings"
session <- html_session(url)

form <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,
                          username = "notmyrealemail",
                          password = "notmyrealpassword")

submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

Here's what I get as output after `submit_form`:

```
<session> https://premium.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-medical-schools/research-rankings
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size:   286846
```

I assume this means it worked? If so, how do I `read_html` on the page that appears after I log in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nvm, got it to work by using `url <- jump_to(session, "https://premium.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-medical-schools/research-rankings")`

Comment: Can you insert that line in the whole code?