# rvest fails when retrieving title of Rakuten Linkshare web

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am using `rvest` to scrape titles from this webpage (you must log-in first to get access): http://cli.linksynergy.com/cli/publisher/links/linkfinder.php?max=25&mode=basic&currec=1&keyword=linux&mid=-1&linklang=pt_BR&eid=RUxZriH*PWc&lsnoid=NONE

I used SelectorGadget to select the 25 items displayed:

[image]

I would like to retrieve the title of those 25 items but I get `character(0)`. This is the code I used:

```
url <-'http://cli.linksynergy.com/cli/publisher/links/linkfinder.php?max=25&mode=basic&currec=1&keyword=linux&mid=-1&linklang=pt_BR'
webpage <- read_html(url)

title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.td_auto_left a:nth-child(1)')

title_data <- html_text(title_data_html)

head(title_data)
character(0)
```

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

I guess it can be a problem of accesing to the web when it has to log-in. If so, how can I tell R to use my user and password to get in?

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve it, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700708/using-rvest-to-scrape-a-website-w-a-login-page):

```
url     <-"https://login.linkshare.com/sso/login" ## page to spider
session <-html_session(url)                       ## create session
form    <-html_form(read_html(session))[[1]]      ## pull form from session


filled_form <- set_values(form,
                          username = "myusername",
                          password = "mypassword")

submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

And then using this code:

```
url <- jump_to(session, "http://cli.linksynergy.com/cli/publisher/links/linkfinder.php?max=100&mode=basic&currec=1&keyword=inkscape&mid=-1&linklang=pt_BR")
```