# Web-scraping with Login using R and rvest does not work

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape information from a webpage which includes statistics of athletics for all athletes. It is necessary to login, but somehow it appears that for the absolute word class, login is not necessary when the URL of that particular athlete is known. That means for instance that I can access data of Usain Bolt

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.tilastopaja.eu/" # url with login form
url_Bolt <- "https://www.tilastopaja.eu/db/at.php?Sex=1&ID=45032" 

#create a web session without using the login
pgsession<-html_session(url)
athletePage <- session_jump_to(pgsession, url_Bolt)
athletePage
```

This shows that it works for the url of Usain Bolt:

```
<session> https://www.tilastopaja.eu/db/at.php?Sex=1&ID=45032
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size:   120109
```

Then I change the athlete ID in the url of another athlete by adding a 2 in front of the ID code into `url_Athlete <- "https://www.tilastopaja.eu/db/at.php?Sex=1&ID=245032"`, which is a less known athlete. For this athlete, a login is needed, however it appears that submitting a form does not work to jump to the athlete results

```
library(rvest)


login <- "https://www.tilastopaja.eu/login.php" # url with login form
url_Athlete <- "https://www.tilastopaja.eu/db/at.php?Sex=1&ID=245032"

#create a web session with the desired login address
pgsession <- html_session(login)
pgform <- html_form(read_html(login))[[5]]  #in this case the login is the 5th form
filled_form <- html_form_set(pgform, user= "userName", password= "passWord") # fill in the username and password

submit_form(pgsession,filled_form) # submit form
athletePage <- session_jump_to(pgsession, url_Athlete)
athletePage
```

This does not work because the session information is not the URL that it should be:

```
<session> https://www.tilastopaja.eu/login.php?p=1
  Status: 200
  Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size:   150849
```

It appears that login did not work. What should I change in order to access data of this athlete? I saw many relating questions at Stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700708/using-rvest-to-scrape-a-website-w-a-login-page), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283185/unable-to-scrape-website-with-form-using-rvest))  but that did not solve my problem. I also tried to add a fake submission button, but did also not work. I am clueless!

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: try `html_form_set(pgform, "user" = "my_username", 
                'password' = 'my_password')`

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, but unfortunately this did not solve the problem.