# Scraping a webpage behind login

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm trying to download my continuous glucose monitoring data from Dexcom Clarity website every 90 days. To access the website where the data is stored requires a login. My login works and I can manually download the data; however, I'd like to write a program that automatically download the latest data every 90 days to a local folder on my computer.

To start, I can't even programmatically login to the website. I am new to webscraping and may be missing something.

I've been following this instructions of this post [Using rvest to scrape a website w/ a login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700708/using-rvest-to-scrape-a-website-w-a-login-page) but cannot get this to work:

```r
library(rvest)

#login
url <- "https://uam1.dexcom.com/"
session <- session(url); session
#> <session> https://uam1.dexcom.com/identity/login?signin=508ddf72a56d3b5eeb405a1a1bd7adf1
#>   Status: 200
#>   Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
#>   Size:   3387
form <- html_form(session); form
#> list()
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The call `html_form(session)` returns an empty list, which is wrong - Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no login page on your `url`

Comment: @NadPat I changed the url - believe it should have the login page now, but still get the same issue. Does the login page display for you when you use the updated `url`? Seems like part of the issue is that the url expands once you actually get to the login page.. not sure the significance of this

Comment: Maybe try using `RSelenium`

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach

```
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
url <- "https://uam1.dexcom.com/"
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("id", "username")
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("my_user_name"))

web_Obj_Password <- remDr$findElement("id", "password")
web_Obj_Password$sendKeysToElement(list("my_password"))

web_Obj_Login <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#edit-actions > input")
web_Obj_Login$clickElement()
```

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://uam1.dexcom.com/"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)

web_Obj_Username <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("username")
web_Obj_Username$Click()
web_Obj_Username$Focus()
web_Obj_Username[["Value"]] <- "my_user_name"

web_Obj_Username <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("password")
web_Obj_Username$Click()
web_Obj_Username$Focus()
web_Obj_Username[["Value"]] <- "my_password"

doc <- IEApp$Document()
clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)
web_Obj_Login <- IEApp$Document()$querySelector("#edit-actions > input")
web_Obj_Login$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a POST request to `https://uam1.dexcom.com/identity/login`

with the parameters `username` and `password` in the request body.

There are two more cryptic parameters that get sent, `signin` as a querystring parameter and `idsrv.xsrf` as a third param in the request body. I don't know if they are required. I just copied the POST request as a curl command from the browser devtools window and looked at the command that got generated (I am not a dexcom customer).